# What is the best way to extend interfaces for a properties bag with defaults at each level of abstraction?

Tags: typescript

I am using an external library with a class and interfaces defined like this:

```js
export interface LibraryCommunicationProps {
  email: string;
  phone: string;
}

export interface LibraryThingProps {
  name: string;
  org: string;
  communicationProps: LibraryCommunicationProps;
}

export declare class LibraryThing {
  constructor(id: string, props: LibraryThingProps);
}
```

In a file that is common to my entire package I have written the following:

```js
export interface PackageCommunicationProps extends Partial<LibraryCommunicationProps> {
    readonly email: 'my-email@package.com'
}

export interface PackageThingCommonProps extends Partial<LibraryThingProps> {
    readonly org: 'MyOrg'
    readonly communicationProps: PackageCommunicationProps
}

export class PackageThingCommon extends LibraryThing {
    constructor(id: string, props: PackageThingCommonProps) {
        super(id, props)
    }
}
```

Then I have a file where the sausage is made:

```js
class SausageThing extends PackageThingCommon {
    constructor(id: string) {
        super('Sausage', {
            name: 'MyName', 
            communicationProps: {
                phone: '555-1234'
            }
         })
        ...
    }
}

const sausage = new SausageThing('my-id')
```

Now I know an interface represents a structure that is *expected* and is not great for defining defaults, but I really can't figure out a way to make make use of the defaults I defined at the various levels of abstraction such that an object with the following structure will be passed as the `props` parameter to `LibraryThing`:

```js
{
  name: 'MyName',
  org: 'MyOrg'
  communicationProps: {
    email: 'my-email@package.com',
    phone: '555-1234'
  }
}
```

This is my latest iteration after trying many combinations of other things including `Omit` and classes instead of interfaces but there's always some issue. There's a very good chance this may be way off base in it's current state.

Anything except what's in the external library can be changed.

Comment: Are you expecting your `Package` types/class to compile? It incorrectly extends the library at the moment because of `Partial`. You've also got three arguments in your `SausageThing` super when `PackageThingCommon` expects two. Maybe I'm missing something, but this seems like a "types don't exist at runtime problem". `PackageThingCommon` must have the actual default string values of `org` and `email` to hand, so it can merge (or overwrite) them with your incomplete prop input at runtime (which you will have to implement).

Comment: @lawrence-witt I edited the args in the `SausageThing` super to match the expectation of `PackageThingCommon`. The `Package` types/classes may not compile. The real bit that matters is that I want the full properties bag to be created as I've shown using the defaults set at the different levels of abstraction. Using `Partial` is just a (possibly foolhardy) attempt at making that work.